# Disable javascript file based on media query portrait mode

Tags: javascript, media-queries, horizontal-scrolling, landscape-portrait

I want to switch from one javascript file to another javascript file on ipad portrait mode (so i can switch from horizontal scrolling tot vertical scrolling on portrait mode).

I have found something like: http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

But i can't find anything to just disable/enable a javascript file based on this query:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need javascript to do this. Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s2meLh85/) and here is the css below:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px)
{
    .container {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot to tell i'm using a horizontal scroll javascript file, the script used on this site: http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/horizontal-website-demo1.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe that CSS media queries are used for styling and responsive design.

I would look at something using javascript itself to dynamically alter included script files.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml give an example

```
function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1)
    allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
}
```

}

removejscssfile("somescript.js", "js") //remove all occurences of "somescript.js" on page
removejscssfile("somestyle.css", "css") //remove all occurences "somestyle.css" on page

I hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: do you know how to use that based on the ipad portrait mode media query?

Comment: I don't know ipad specific javascript code but i was able to dig up this blog post about javascript and media queries [Using media queries in JavaScript](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Using-media-queries-in-JavaScript-AbsurdJS-edition) it seems to do some of the things you are asking about

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using media queries in javascript in the external javascript file itself (it's only one line that causes the vertical/horizontal change):

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)');if(mq.matches) {$(document).ready(function () {$.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'y'; $.localScroll(); });} else {$(document).ready(function () {$.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'x'; $.localScroll(); });}
```

more info: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Using-media-queries-in-JavaScript-AbsurdJS-edition

although i have to refresh the page before it works, but i didnt tested on a real ipad yet..